# Why is Gragas not considered a top mid/top?

Tags: league-of-legends

Gragas is a rare pick, especially in tournaments. His poke, sustain and escape are all pretty good, and his ult provides a little extra CC.

What are his weaknesses due to which he is not picked up often?

Comment: Hi, Mozzykaze.  I've voted to close your question because it's basically soliciting opinions.  Since the whole point of Arqade is questions and answers, we like questions that can provide concrete answers; these types of questions can't do that.

Comment: Hey Mozzykaze, welcome to Arqade! And thanks for taking the time to ask a question! Here at Arqade, we're not only trying to answer people's questions, we're also trying to build a resource for future users. So when you ask a question, try imagining if a future user would have the same question and would benefit from the answers. Although you may have noticed that Gragas is rarely picked in tournaments right now, what if Riot buffs Gragas in future patches? Or what if a famous player starts to pick Gragas frequently? Unfortunately, then this question will make a lot less sense.

Comment: We know that these are high standards to expect of every question, but we hope that these expectations will help us create a gaming reference that we are proud of. Overall, don't worry too much about the downvotes and the question closure: those effects are transient.

Comment: A better question may be, "What are Gragas' strengths and weaknesses as an AP mid?" In your question description, you can explain that you've noticed that Gragas is rarely picked in tournament games. Bonus points if you can cite a source that shows that Gragas has been underrepresented in tournaments. A good answer to this question will then include an analysis of Gragas, hopefully in comparison to other champions, in the context of competitive gaming.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the reason he isn't chosen much in competitive play is the same reason that champions like Cho'Gath aren't chosen; they rely on skillshots to do damage. Gragas can do anywhere from 0% to 100% of his damage in a teamfight, which is a gamble many teams don't want to chance. There are many other champions who can poke with less repercussions for missing skillshots such as AP kog due to his ult's low cooldown.

Comment: This is very true, I find many times in lane that the barrels can be very scary, but if they miss then I feel a little useless.

Answer (score 1):

It's because his Q is sometimes difficult to hit, and his ult can make or break a teamfight very easily, while it is good for saving someone's life. But his abilities can reset a teamfight. Gragas also takes a skill level to play him on his skillshots.

Answer (score 1):

I think another reason why he might not be a top pick is that his cooldowns are insanely long even with 40% CDR. He can do a lot of damage (skillshots). However, if you miss them, you really can't do much for a while.

There are just a lot of other champions that do the same thing and are just much better at it. Any champ like Ahri (poke with Q, spellvamp for sustain, ult for escape), Morgana (Dark Binding/Tormented Soil for poke, spellshield for defense, CC if ult channeled), et cetera.